# Preprocessing categorical data already converted into numbers

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, preprocessor

I'm fairly new to machine learning, so I don't know the correct terminology, but I converted two categorical columns into numbers the following way. These columns are part of my features inputs, akin to the  sex column in the titanic database. 
(They are not the target data `y` which I have already created)

```
                           changed  p_changed  
Date                                       
2010-02-17   0.477182        0          0  
2010-02-18   0.395813        0          0  
2010-02-19   0.252179        1          1  
2010-02-22   0.401321        0          1  
2010-02-23   0.519375        1          1
```

Now the rest of my data `X`looks something like this

```
          Open  High   Low  Close    Volume  Adj Close  log_return  \
Date                                                                   
2010-02-17  2.07  2.07  1.99   2.03  219700.0       2.03   -0.019513   
2010-02-18  2.03  2.03  1.99   2.03  181700.0       2.03    0.000000   
2010-02-19  2.03  2.03  2.00   2.02  116400.0       2.02   -0.004938   
2010-02-22  2.05  2.05  2.02   2.04  188300.0       2.04    0.009852   
2010-02-23  2.05  2.07  2.01   2.05  255400.0       2.05    0.004890   

            close_open  Daily_Change  30_Avg_Vol  20_Avg_Vol  15_Avg_Vol  \
Date                                                                       
2010-02-17        0.00         -0.04    0.909517    0.779299    0.668242   
2010-02-18        0.00          0.00    0.747470    0.635404    0.543015   
2010-02-19        0.00         -0.01    0.508860    0.417706    0.348761   
2010-02-22        0.03         -0.01    0.817274    0.666903    0.562414   
2010-02-23        0.01          0.00    1.078411    0.879007    0.742730
```

As you can see the rest of my data is continuous (containing many variables) as opposed to the two categorical columns which only have two values (0 and 1).

I was planning to preprocess all this data in one shot via this simple preprocess method

```
X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X)
```

I was wondering if this is mistake? Is there something else I need to do to the categorical values before using this simple preprocessing?

EDIT: I tried two ways; First I  tried scaling the full data, including the categorical data converted to 1's and 0's.

```
Full_X = OPK_df.iloc[:-5, 0:-5]
Full_X_scaled = preprocessing.scale( Full_X)   # First way, which scales everything in one shot.
```

Then I tried dropping the last two columns, scaling, then adding the dropped columns via this code.

```
X =OPK_df.iloc[:-5, 0:-7]   # Here I'm dropping both -7 while originally the offset was only till -5, which means two extra columns were dropped.
```

I created another dataframe which has those two columns I dropped

```
 x2 =OPK_df.iloc[:-5, -7:-5]
 x2 = np.array(x2)   # convert it to an array


 # preprocessing the data without last two columns
   from sklearn import preprocessing
   X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X)

# Then concact the X_scaled with x2(originally dropped columns)

   X =np.concatenate((X_scaled, x2), axis =1)


    #Creating a classifier

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn2 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn.fit(X_scaled, y)
knn2.fit(X,y)


knn.score(Full_X_scaled, y)

0.71396522714526078


knn2.score(X, y)

0.71789119461581608
```

So there is a higher score when I do indeed drop the two columns during standarization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing pretty well so far.  Do *not* scale your classification data.  Since those appear to be binary classifications, think of this as "Yes" and "No".  What does it mean to scale these?

Even worse, consider that you might have classifications such as flower types: you've coded Zinnia=0, Rose=1, Orchid=2, etc.  What does it meant to scale those?  It doesn't make any sense to re-code these as Zinnia=-0.257, Rose=+0.448, etc.

Scaling your *input* data is the necessary part: it keeps the values within comparable ranges (mathematical influence), allowing you to readily use a single treatment for your loss function.  Otherwise, the feature with the largest spread of values would have the greatest influence on training, until your model's weights learned how to properly discount the large values.

For your beginning explorations, don't do any other preprocessing: just scale the input data and start your fitting exercises.

Comment: Hi. I think I made a mistake in my wording. The last two columns`changed  p_changed ` which have categorical data, are part of my input data. It's akin to `sex` in the titanic database.  My output (classification ) column is a totally different column, which I have already converted to `y`.  So should I try to drop these drop columns, then scale the rest of the data, and then add the columns back? Thank you.

Comment: Ah; I see.  Yes, you're exactly correct: don't scale those, if it's easy to avoid.  It won't hurt, but it will make the intermediate data harder to read.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and see if it improves my classifier's score.

Comment: Thanks. I saw a slight improvement by dropping the columns, scaling and adding back the columns. I think I did it correctly. (I'm not used to using numpy as much as I am Pandas)

Comment: Strange; I would expect that it makes no difference in the results.  The accuracy changed -- statistically significant?

Comment: Only about half-a-percent upgrade. Though when I play around with different hyperparameters the percentage goes upto about .8% or so. However, my model is very bad at the moment.  I updated the OP showing the percentage change.